# CSS Locator with contains() InvalidSelectorException using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am learning ***Selenium Webdriver*** and trying to write a simple test script.

The intent is to get the `About Google` link on ***Gmail*** page so as to practice ***CSS locators***.

***Here is the code:***

```
public class GoogleSearch {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();         
        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
        
        WebElement aboutGoogle = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a:contains('About Google')"));          
    
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();          
    }    
}
```

I get the below-mentioned exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector a:contains('About Google') is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
Command duration or timeout: 356 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
System info: host: 'XXXXX', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-49-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=a:contains('Need')}
Session ID: 0f1869f8-c59a-4f61-b1c7-b34ada42573f
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

I had checked and was able to find the element in Selenium IDE using the same locator.

I read somewhere that the `findElement()` method is returning a ***DOM node*** and the code is expecting a WebElement object.

If this is the case then, is there a workaround/casting?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CssSelector` does not work in scripting but it works in selenium IDE.

It's also not good to work on sites like gmail.

Comment: Well that  is the point I wanted to confirm. I was trying the locators from the IDE and the one I used was not working. BTW, I picked up the list from https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors (Inner Text) and thought they were applicable for webdriver scripting as well.

Comment: @SandeepDharembra `contains()` doesn't work for css locators, for selenium Web Driver. See my answer for more info.

Comment: There's no longer any page at seleniumtrainer.com - that URL is now for sale from GoDaddy. Does that page still exist, and if so, can you update the link?

Comment: Hi..presently it is down.. Sorry for that.. Will update you once it is up.

Comment: @samjewell, sorry for that my site is down and looking for good developer to make it again. meanwhile you can use this http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 32):

The main problem is at this line:

> driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a:contains('About Google')"));

`css` doesn't maintain `contains()` for Selenium WD - [See here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=987).

For using `contains()` you have to use [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

With ***Xpath*** your locator will be:

> //a[contains(text(), 'About Google')]

and for driver it will be as:

> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'About Google')]"));

For finding *links with Selenium* you can use:

> driver.findElement(By.linkText("your link name here"));

It is limitation of ***CSS*** selectors compare to ***Xpath***:

- you can't take parent element with CSS selectors (Xpath has XPath axes)
- you can't use contains (it is only XPath privilege).

***BTW***
For processing ***Xpath*** locators from page you able to use extension for Firefox browser:

- [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/uk/firefox/addon/firepath/)
- [Xpath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/)

Comment: Actually, "Contains" is done in css via *=, e.g. [attribute*='value'] Similarly, ^= and $= mean begins and ends with respectively.

Comment: @JonNelson I misunderstand your point. can you show some example usage related to question situation? For replacing this xpath - `//a[contains(text(), 'About Google')]`

Comment: I noticed that Selenium internally converted `By.cssSelector("div[data-testid ^='avatar']")` to `By.xpath("//div[contains(data-testid,'avatar')]")`

Answer (score 0):

Well as the Exception is clearly stating the problem here is that your Css Selector is not valid. 'You are trying to get the `About Google` anchor tag **based on it's text which is not a valid css selector**'. It's more of a jQuery selector.

You could use the selector based on the value of href attribute as shown below and it will work fine.

```
 #footer-list a[href*='about']
```

and use it like

```
WebElement aboutGoogle = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#footer-list a[href*='about']"));
```