# why cssSelector in selenium unable to identify the text

Tags: css, selenium

I wanna know if i can identify the element based on text of the element, div or link using css only. Is that possible? Because i am not able to use contains method for cssselector.

Please provide the css selector syntax for the below html.

Ex- "Hi There"

Comment: CSS selectors are for identifying elements by their relationship to the page or their surrounding elements -- not by their text content. The xpath, link_text and partial_link_text descriptors do provide the ability to identify elements by their content. Link and partial link are fairly straightforward, but there are a whole bunch of ways to use xpath. Search the net for some. Here is an [IBM document describing xpath syntax](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAE4W_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref2.doc/rbafzxpathqueryexmp.htm).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Locator with contains() InvalidSelectorException using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999630/css-locator-with-contains-invalidselectorexception-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

No.
You can use XPATH to do it.